# Java Bubblesort is only swapping 1st array item

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, sorting, bubble-sort

my bubble sort code is only swapping the 1st array item. All other items are left as 0. I think my nested loops are wrong or something I haven't been able to diagnose it correctly yet. so here is my code.

```
    public void swap(int i, int j) {

    int temp;

    temp = i;
    i = j;
    j = temp;
}


public void sortArray(int [] sourceArray, int [] targetArray, int allArraySize){

    for(int i = 0; i < allArraySize; i++) {
        targetArray[i] = sourceArray[i];
        for (i = 0; i < allArraySize; i++) {
            for(int j = i+1; j < allArraySize;j++) {
                if(targetArray[i] > targetArray[j]) {
                    swap(i, j);
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

thanks so much for the feedback. I am (obviously) new to programming. I have changed my code to this.

```
public void sortArray(int [] sourceArray, int [] targetArray, int allArraySize){
    int temp;

    for(int i = 0; i < allArraySize; i++) {
        targetArray[i] = sourceArray[i];
        for (i = 0; i < allArraySize; i++) {
            for(int j = i+1; j < allArraySize;j++) {
                if(targetArray[i] > targetArray[j]) {
                    temp = targetArray[i];
                    targetArray[i] = targetArray[j];
                    targetArray[j] = temp;
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

and the result is still only swapping 1 item but now it is the last 1. if anyone is still able to help I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is explained in detail in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference). In summary, java passes arguments by value and your `swap` method only swaps local variables but has no effect on the variables in your `sortArray` method.

An easy fix would be to include the code of `swap` directly in your `if`. Note: I have not checked the rest of your code. For example, you probably meant to swap the elements in the array rather than the indexes.

Comment: plus, in order to do it in a swap() method, you will need something like: `void swap(int i, int j, int[] arr) { int temp = arr[i]; arr[i] = arr[j]; arr[j] = temp;  }`

Answer (score 1):

You are using two times the i counter:

```
for(int i = 0; i < allArraySize; i++) {
    targetArray[i] = sourceArray[i];
        for (i = 0; i < allArraySize; i++) {
        ...
```

Possibly the inner loop is making overwriting the i counter that are used in your outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

(Please note that this is my first post to Stackoverflow. I've programmed in many languages, none of which are truly O-O. I've been attacking Java for a month or so in spare time.)

As in the original code in msg 1, I felt the need to do the swapping via a separate procedure, since doing so works just great (and is encouraged) in Pascal, VBasic, etc. as part of the "divide-and-conquer" programming practice. So it was quite puzzling to me, too, why my identical *swap* routine didn't work in Java... until I **re**-read about parameter passing. I finally got it through my head that the **array itself** needed to be passed in order to change its contents.

```
public static void swap(int [] a, int i, int j) {
    int c  = a[i];
      a[i] = a[j];
      a[j] = c;
  }
```

The above worked for me, and as much as I've struggled to absorb Java, I'm actually proud that I finally figured it out. But geez.... pretty routine thing to be baffled by, huh?

On the other hand, I guess I learned what **by reference** means as well as how to cope with it.

And I guess I unwittingly **encapsulated** the *swap* method's workings, thereby following an O-O tenet. So... double good?

But this makes me ask: Is it just a goofy idea to "divide and conquer" sorting to this extent? After all, moving the 3-line swap routine inline with the rest of the sort routine is common sense, but is my *swap* method just silly or, if not "best", then at least "good" Java practice?